# How to check if an asset exists

Tags: pallet, assets

I'm using `pallet-assets` to implement my own pallet. In one of the extrinsic calls I would like to check if an asset with the given ID exists. How to achieve this, given that `Assets` type is private and there's no getter provided?

Comment: Maybe checking its `assets.asset(u32): Option<PalletAssetsAssetDetails>`?

Comment: @ArturGontijo Where is that? Can you paste a link to the docs or code?

Comment: Like a `get` on https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L249 ?

Comment: @ArturGontijo That's what I tried at first, but the type is private so the compiler says 'no-no'.

Comment: I remember doing something like that following this approach https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-use-storage-and-functions-from-one-custom-pallet-in-another but maybe things have changed.

Comment: @ArturGontijo Perhaps it works if the pallet re-exports the storage type alias as pub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use maybe_total_supply. This will return Some(supply) if the asset exists, and None otherwise
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/assets/src/functions.rs#L62

Comment: That's a good one. For some reason `maybe_total_supply` is not mentioned in [the docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_assets/pallet/struct.Pallet.html).

Answer (score 1):

After you create the asset with for example `pallet_assets::Pallet::<T>::force_create` query `pallet_assets::<T>::Balance` with the asset id

```rust
let assetid: AssetId<T> = 1337u32.into();
let asset_balance: u128 = pallet_assets::Pallet::<T>::balance(assetid.into(), myaccount)
                .try_into()
                .unwrap_or(0u128);
```

Comment: This assumes I have an account `myaccount` with non-zero balance of the asset, which is not quite my case.